# F# polymorphism in function return types

Tags: f#, polymorphism

Here's a simple type hierarchy.

```
type Parent() = class end
type Child() = inherit Parent()
```

I want to treat a function of type `('x -> Child)` as `('x -> Parent)`:

```
let f (x: 'x): Child = new Child()
let g: ('x -> Parent) = f // error
```

But that last assignment fails, with the message `The type 'Parent' does not match the type 'Child'`. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: This appears to be co/contravariance, which is not supported in F#.
http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5663470-provide-covariance-contravariance-language-support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [upcast operator (:>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx) to make it work :

```
type Parent () = class end
type Child () = inherit Parent ()

let f x = Child () // val f : x:'a -> Child
let g x = f x :> Parent // val g : x:'a -> Parent
```

Comment: This is helpful, but having to wrap `f` isn't ideal. I'd like to be able to, for example, add f to a `Map<'a, ('b -> Parent)>` without a lot of dickering.